# How to close a tab and open a new tab using Selenium RC

Tags: java, selenium-rc

I'm working on selenium RC java. In my test case, I have to close a tab and then open a new tab in the same test case. Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Selenium IDE to **record** these scenarios? That's what I would try first.

Alternatively, try firing a `Ctrl+T` event to open a new tab:

```
selenium.keyDownNative("17");
selenium.keyPressNative("84");
selenium.keyUpNative("17");
```

and `Ctrl+W` to close the tab:

```
selenium.keyDownNative("17");
selenium.keyPressNative("87");
selenium.keyUpNative("17");
```

Answer (score 0):

To open new tab:

```
Robot r = new Robot(); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

And close the tab opened:

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
```