# Multiple Window problem in SELENIUM IDE

Tags: ide, selenium, selenium-ide

HI,

I am using Selenium IDE for recording test cases. In a particular test case, I need to work on two windows simultaneously but the selenium IDE does not record when I open a new tab and work on it. Can anyone give me suggestions on this?

awaiting replies !

Answer (score 2):

You can try that programmatically as suggested here 
[How to close a tab and open a new tab using Selenium RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780852/how-to-close-a-tab-and-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-rc)

You can open the other window (considered popup by selenium i guess) like so

```
selenium.openWindow("http://example.com/","dev");
selenium.selectWindow("dev");
selenium.open("/");
```

and then you switch b/w the windows . to go back to original one you will have to do

```
selenium.selectWindow(null);
```